# Super Metroid Grappling Beam Challenge

Tags: super-metroid

Now that I've found the Grappling Beam in Super Metroid, I'm going back through old areas to collect upgrades I couldn't get before.

One place in Norfair that really caught my attention is only reachable by grappling those invincible flying things:

[image: Hanging out]

Problem is, it's super challenging because you have to go airborne 4 times, grappling onto those things while they move. I've already wasted an hour trying to perform the grappling, but is it worth getting over there? What can I expect to find?

That unexplored blue square to the top right of the room is killing me!

[image: Argh!]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're tired of using the grappling beam, it is also possible to get a speedboost charge from the ramp along the lower right, then shinespark directly up, bypassing the need for the grappling beam all together.

Other than that, it all comes down to persistence, regardless of which way you try to get there.

Comment: But what's in there?

Comment: Or screw attack all the way up.  Takes longer, but it still works.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft I want to say a missile expansion.

Comment: What is the screw attack? Oh man I think I'm too early into the game :D

Comment: Yeah, it's a missile expansion. (I won't link it, but the determined can find a spoiler/walkthrough by searching for `retropixel missile locations`.)

Comment: Spinesharking is the way to go. I could also wall-jump but that's really frustrating to execute more than once.